# I am trying to create a bcp command line that will convert my SQL view to a CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a `bcp` command line that will convert my SQL view to a CSV file.

This is my code:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [dba].[schema Name].LeaveExtract" queryout "C:\Temp\myExport.csv" -T -c -t,'
go
```

I keep getting this error:

> -SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
>   -Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>   -SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
>   -Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   -SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
>   -Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
>   NULL

I made sure that my named pipes and TCP/IP are enabled and that my services are running. I don't seen to know what the problem is.

Comment: First check, are you able to connect to your `server/database` using your `NTID`?

Comment: Under what account `sql services` are running ?

Comment: You can provide your SQL Server Name in above command i.e., -S ServerName

Comment: @abhishek yes i can connect

Comment: I guess BCP utility is not responding and causing timeouts while querying, you need to change `-T -c -t'. How long query is executing before throwing error ?

Comment: @BHouse under sql server analysis services

Comment: @james - ok thats good, but looks like you are missing `-S ServerName` in your `bcp` query.

Comment: @BHouse its taking 16 secs

Comment: You are missing some more info apart from @@servername

Comment: what else am i missing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Method, Enter all required parameters for `bcp` and `cmdshell`

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM [dba].[schema Name].LeaveExtract" queryout "C:\Temp\myExport.csv" -C -T -S ' + @@servername + ' -T -t -c -C 65001'

PRINT @sql

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

Comment: thanks man that worked but after a few seconds it pops that error again

Comment: Check in SQL services , which account it is running under ?

Comment: Right click SQL Server instance -> Properties -> Connections ->  Check the Allow remote connections to this server box

Comment: And also check what permissions your account  have at server level

Comment: well i did allow remote connections

Comment: Try logging into server with `sa` account and execute the query

Comment: SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 10061
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 10061
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is config
ured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.